# Overlay of color plots with 2 color scales ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Attempting to overlay color plots (something like below) using ggplot2

[image: Red + Green giving Yellow in the 3rd column]

Trying to use geom_tile but ggplot doesnt allow me to add 2 color scales. Here is an example code.

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(1:5,1:5))
df$z1 <- runif(nrow(df))
df$z2 <- runif(nrow(df))
g1 <- ggplot(df,aes(Var1,Var2)) + theme_bw()
#layer 1
g11 <- g1  + geom_tile(aes(fill=z1),alpha=0.5) + scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red")
#layer 2
g12 <- g1  + geom_tile(aes(fill=z2),alpha=0.5) + scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="green")
g11
g12
```

One way to possible do this is to make the 2 layers as different groups. But the outcome just doesn't look intuitive.

```
mdf=melt(df,'id'=1:2)
g2 <- ggplot(mdf,aes(Var1,Var2,fill = factor(variable),alpha = value)) + 
     geom_tile() + scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','green')) + theme_bw()
g2
```

[image: best outcome i could come up with]

Answer (score 3):

You're really close: just don't divide z1 and z2 by 2.

There is another issue to consider though. If z1 and z2 are not on the same scale, should you use a common scale for both, or should you scale them independently? The result is (can be) different, as illustrated below.

```
gg.overlay <- function(df) {  # produces 2 color channels and the overlay
  require(ggplot2)
  require(gridExtra)
  gg.z1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
    geom_tile(fill=rgb(red=df$z1.scale,green=0,blue=0))+
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    coord_fixed()

  gg.z2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
    geom_tile(fill=rgb(red=0,green=df$z2.scale,blue=0))+
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    coord_fixed()

  gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
    geom_tile(fill=rgb(red=df$z1.scale,green=df$z2.scale,blue=0))+
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    coord_fixed()

  library(gridExtra)
  grid.arrange(gg.z1, gg.z2, gg, ncol=3)
}
```

Using an example slightly closer to the image in your question:

```
library(mvtnorm)  # just for this example
df    <- expand.grid(x=seq(-3,3,len=100),y=seq(-3,3,len=100))
df$z1 <- with(df,dmvnorm(cbind(x,y),mean=c(0,0),sigma=matrix(c(1,-1,-1,2),nc=2)))
df$z2 <- with(df,3*dmvnorm(cbind(x,y),mean=c(0,0),sigma=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),nc=2)))

# scale z1 and z2 together
max.z <- with(df,max(z1,z2))
min.z <- with(df,min(z1,z2))
df$z1.scale <- with(df, (z1-min.z)/(max.z-min.z))
df$z2.scale <- with(df, (z2-min.z)/(max.z-min.z))
gg.overlay(df)
```

[image]

```
# scale z1 and z2 separately
df$z1.scale <- with(df, (z1-min(z1))/diff(range(z1)))
df$z2.scale <- with(df, (z2-min(z2))/diff(range(z2)))
gg.overlay(df)
```

[image]

In the first case the reds are muted because the `z1` intensities are lower than the `z2` intensities. In the second case we scale them separately, so the reds are more vibrant. It's not clear which is the "correct" method.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to manually calculate the color and then pass it to geom_tile. (continuation to the above code)

```
cols=rgb(red=df$z1/2,green=df$z2/2,blue=rep(0,nrow(df)))
g1 <- ggplot(df,aes(Var1,Var2)) + theme_bw() + geom_tile(fill=cols)
g1
```

[image: but it is too dark]

How do i brighten the colors?